# Why does the pw_passwd field of the struct returned by getpwnam not contain my password hash?

Tags: c, linux

I could not get suckless' slock to work, and the issue came down to **getpwnam** returning a struct where **pw_passwd** is set as "x". It does not work regardless of whether the user name given to **getpwnam** is a normal user or root, or whether the user running the program is a normal user or root.

As an example, this code always prints "*pw_passwd : x*", regardles of how **username** is set and who is running the program.

```c
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct passwd *p;
char user[] = "username";

int main()
{
  if ( ( p = getpwnam( user ) ) == NULL )
    perror( "getpwnam() error" );
  else
  {
    printf( "pw_passwd : %s\n", p->pw_passwd );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I expect to get the hash of the password, not the password itself.

The problem I am trying to solve in the end is that in this file:

https://git.suckless.org/slock/file/slock.c.html

where I get the error on line *345*, which I assume is because the value **x** does not work for the function, which as far as I can tell expects the actual hash.

**EDIT 2:**

I realize I asked the question wrong, the problem is that I have the same issue with **getspnam**, which is supposed to read the shadow file. Sorry about that.

**EDIT 3:**

An actual example of code not working would be this, which prints "*" as a normal user and "**!**" as root instead of the password hash:

```c
#include <pwd.h>
#include <shadow.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const char *gethash( void )
{
  const char *hash;
  struct passwd *pw;

  if ( !( pw = getpwuid( getuid() ) ) )
  {
    return "";
  }
  hash = pw->pw_passwd;

  if ( !strcmp( hash, "x" ) )
  {
    struct spwd *sp;
    if ( !( sp = getspnam( pw->pw_name ) ) )
      return "";
    hash = sp->sp_pwdp;
  }

  return hash;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", gethash());
}
```

Comment: Did you investigate the issue? Did you inspect the `man getpwnam`? The value `x` for `pw_passwd` is a valid value.

Comment: The password is stored hashed in `/etc/shadow`. You can't retrieve the actual password even as root.

Comment: As @Erlkoenig said, nowadays these hashes are most stored in /etc/shadow. Check out http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/passwd.5.html and the paragraph stating `These days many people run some version of the shadow
       password suite, where /etc/passwd has an 'x' character in the
       password field, and the encrypted passwords are in /etc/shadow, which
       is readable by the superuser only.`

Comment: Please alter the code and show us exactly what you were trying to read the shadow file.

Comment: At the cost of repeating what @Trickzter and Erlkoenig mentioned, for EDIT 3 -- (i) you will have to run above program as `root` since `/etc/shadow` will only be readble by root user, and (ii) you are using `getuid()` so you are trying to get hash password for root user. In your distribution (e.g. Ubuntu), direct login as root must have been disabled by setting hash as "*" or "!" in `/etc/shadow`. You must be using `sudo` command to work as a root user.  Try replacing "getuid()" with some real user id by checking /etc/passwd's 3rd column, compile and run again.